# Using VBA and Internet Explorer to Parse HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to use VBA code to click a "Go" button on a website. This is the source code.

```
 <div class="actions"> 
  <a id="go" href="javascript:void(null);" title="Go"><img src="/images/button-go-smaller.png"></a>
   <a id="reset" href="javascript:void(null);" title="Reset All Fields"><img src="/images/button-reset_all.png"></a>
                    </div>
```

This is my VBA code:

```
For Each obj In objCollection
     If objCollection(i).ID = "go" Then
        Set objElement = obj
Exit For
    End If
Next obj
objElement.Click
```

However, on the  objElement.Click line, I get an error 91, which means that the "go" action cannot be found. Why is that, and how can I access the go button?

Comment: Why are you using the object collection index when you are already looping through the object collection with the `obj` variable? Also you are not incrementing `i` through each loop.

Answer (score 2):

What about...

```
Dim objCollection As Object
Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("a")

For Each obj In objCollection
    If obj.ID = "go" Then
        obj.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next obj
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an html object having an `Id` you can get it direcly with something like this:

```
Dim GoObj As Object
Set GoObj = IE.Document.getElementbyId("go")
'Only if it was found you click it
If not GoObj is Nothing then
    GoObj.Click
End If
```

Pay attention to the difference between element in `getElementbyId` and element**s** in `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of how to do exactly that.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Read more at: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html#XwwFWylLQi9rjILC.99